# How to stop postback to server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, jquery-events

I am using Checkbox select-all and Deselect all if user not selecting any role alert is showing please select at least one Role.
But the page is Redirecting to Server only reason of this I am getting this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

**How can I solve this? Please help me.**

This is the code:

```
$("#selectallchk").hide();
$("#lblselect").hide();
var siteMap = {
    detailsFormId: "#site-map-details-form",
    onSubmit: function(e) {
        siteMap.setRoles();
    },
    validation: function () {
        var validator = $("#site-map-details-form").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
        if (!validator.validate()) {
            $(".k-invalid:first").focus();
        }
        var roles = siteMap.setRoles();
        $("#site-map-details-form").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
        $(".k-invalid:first").focus();
        if($('.site-map-access-roles').is(':checked'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {  
            alert("Please Select at least One Role."); //not checked
            return false;
        }
    },
    setRoles: function() {
        var selectedIds = [];
        $(".site-map-access-roles:checked").each(function(ind, ele) {
            selectedIds.push($(ele).attr("name").trim());
        });
        $("#AccessRoleIds").val(selectedIds);

        if(selectedIds===null)
        {
         alert("Please Select at least One Rols."); //checked
                   return false;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you add templates data ..?

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, show the markup where you call these.